# How do the Japanese ask questions about language?

Tags: questions, learning, linguistics, parts-of-speech

In Japanese class, when you are confused about vocab or grammar or sentence structure, you ask the professor in English. But if you live in Japan and are communicating with Japanese natives who barely speak English, how would you ask about the language in Japanese?

For example, I already know some things like 「Aはどういう意味ですか？」to ask about the meaning of "A" and 「AとBの違いは何ですか？」to ask about the difference between A and B and 「Aっていう文例のもっと自然な言い方は何ですか？」to ask about a more natural way to say A.

But what about the more complicated questions, such as:

- "In which situations would A be better to use instead of B, and vice versa?"
- "What kind of nuances are emphasized with this choice of vocabulary usage?"
- "So I can't use A here because B is a type of (preposition, transitive verb, gerund form, etc.) right?"
- "How can I modify this sentence if I want sarcasm to be obvious to the listener?"

And what would be the natural way to inquire about these kind of topics? i.e. How would a Japanese person ask another Japanese person these questions?

Any example Japanese questions you can think of that can be used specifically to ask about how the language works would be greatly appreciated! I would ideally like to compile a list that anyone can use when they get confused while speaking with natives.

Learning more about Japanese by asking in Japanese and learning from Japanese explanations is so much better for true understanding than simply training your brain to mentally translate. よろしくお願いします！

Comment: この質問って英和翻訳依頼になるんでしょうかね・・・

Comment: "learning from Japanese explanations." I think you answered yourself. Although this may be 英和翻訳依頼, I feel like there is an underlying question. If you want to learn how they say stuff about language, immerse yourself in that topic (in the lnguage)! An easy way to do that is to read about that topic. I suggest reading yahoo知恵袋 questions about say English, or Japanese nuaces

Answer (score 4):

## English

Since the question seems asking for Japanese translation, I know that pure translation is a violation of the rules of this site, but I dare to answer the question because I would like to tell the questioner what would be a natural Japanese language.

1. Before answering the question, I'll explain the background of Japanese language and how Japanese people feel.
   At first I would like to say that in conversation between Japanese people, there would be no such formal question. The reason is that if you make such a formal question, you may be deemed somewhat strange.
   Japanese people who are afraid of being thought to be strange in their interpersonal relationships will not dare to ask this kind of questions in exchange for being considered to be a strange person even if they want to ask questions about Japanese language.
   For other reasons, unless it is a question asked to a person with a difference in Japanese ability so much (for example, to a professor of Japanese linguistics at the university), there is a possibility that the questioner is regarded as a stupid person not understanding Japanese language well. Everyone thinks it would be better not to ask questions like this, if this kind of misunderstanding would possibly occur when he/she asks questions about Japanese language.
   Even so, if we want to resolve questions about Japanese language, we would think to look it up in the dictionaries by ourselves or check them on the Internet.
   When asking questions on the Internet, the expressions posted by the questioner seem to safely exist.
2. I'll tell the appropriate expressions that would be used when asking on the Internet. There are two kinds of expressions: one is literal translation for given English and the other is natural Japanese.

   - "In which situations would A be better to use instead of B, and vice versa?"
     【literal translation】 どのようなときにＢよりＡの方が良い使われ方でしょうか。逆に、Ｂの方がいい場合はどのようなときですか。
     【natural Japanese】 私は「〇〇〇〇〇」のようなときＢよりＡを使った方が良いと思うのですが如何ですか。私の例に関わらずＢよりＡを使った方が良いと思われる例があったら教えてください。また、逆にＢの方が良いと思われる例もお願いします。
   - "What kind of nuances are emphasized with this choice of vocabulary usage?"
     【literal translation】 この言葉を使った場合、どのようなニュアンスが強調されますか。
     【natural Japanese】 私は「〇〇〇◆◆◆〇〇〇〇」と言う文で「◆◆◆」を使って「★★★★」というニュアンスを強く伝えたいのですが、「◆◆◆」の使い方としてそれで合っていますか。それとも「◆◆◆」では何か別のニュアンスが伝わってしまいますか。
   - "So I can't use A here because B is a type of (preposition, transitive verb, gerund form, etc.) right?"
     【literal translation】 Ｂは（  ）なので、ここではＡを使えないのですね。
     【natural Japanese】 same as the literal translation
   - "How can I modify this sentence if I want sarcasm to be obvious to the listener?"
     【literal translation】 聞き手に皮肉さを明確に示したいのですがこの文をどのように修正すればいいですか。
     【natural Japanese】 次のような文を書いています。皮肉さがもっとストレートに伝わるように表現を変えたいのですがうまくいきません。アイデアをよろしくお願いします。

note: I'll introduce the following things that I noticed when I was considering the translation in "natural Japanese". Before asking questions straightly, you are better to present your own attempt at first. If you do so, respondents could understand the purpose of the question well and they are easy to answer properly.

## 日本語

日本語翻訳を尋ねているような質問ですので、このサイトのルール違反のような気もしますが、自然な日本語を理解いただくために敢えて回答します。

1. 回答に先立って前提条件を言います。
   日本人同士の「会話」ではこのような改{あらた}まった質問はまずないでしょう。
   その理由は、もしこのような改まった質問をすると、質問者自身が何か変な人だと思われる恐れがあるからです。対人関係で変に思われることを恐れる日本人は、例え日本語の中で聞きたいことがあっても、変な人だと思われるぐらいなら敢えて質問しないと思います。
   それ以外の理由として、余程日本語能力に差がある人との間での質問でない限り、質問した人が質問された人に、「この人、日本語が良く分かっていない」と思われる可能性もあります。このように思われるぐらいなら質問しない方がましだと誰もが思います。
   それでも問題を解決したい場合には、自分で辞書で調べるかインターネットで調べると思います。
   インターネットで質問する場合には質問者が挙げたような質問表現は十分あり得ます。
2. インターネットで尋ねるとして回答します。
   回答には２種類あります。英語の逐語訳的なものと自然な日本語の２種類です。

   - "In which situations would A be better to use instead of B, and vice versa?"
     【逐語訳】どのようなときにＢよりＡの方が良い使われ方でしょうか。逆に、Ｂの方がいい場合はどのようなときですか。
     【自然な日本語】私は「〇〇〇〇〇」のようなときＢよりＡを使った方が良いと思うのですが如何ですか。私の例に関わらずＢよりＡを使った方が良いと思われる例があったら教えてください。また、逆にＢの方が良いと思われる例もお願いします。
   - "What kind of nuances are emphasized with this choice of vocabulary usage?"
     【逐語訳】この言葉を使った場合、どのようなニュアンスが強調されますか。
     【自然な日本語】私は「〇〇〇◆◆◆〇〇〇〇」と言う文で「◆◆◆」を使って「★★★★」というニュアンスを強く伝えたいのですが、「◆◆◆」の使い方としてそれで合っていますか。それとも「◆◆◆」では何か別のニュアンスが伝わってしまいますか。
   - "So I can't use A here because B is a type of (preposition, transitive verb, gerund form, etc.) right?"
     【逐語訳】Ｂは（）なので、ここではＡを使えないのですね。
     【自然な日本語】逐語訳で十分。
   - "How can I modify this sentence if I want sarcasm to be obvious to the listener?"
     【逐語訳】聞き手に皮肉さを明確に示したいのですがこの文をどのように修正すればいいですか。
     【自然な日本語】次のような文を書いています。皮肉さがもっとストレートに伝わるように表現を変えたいのですがうまくいきません。アイデアをよろしくお願いします。

**note**: 【自然な日本語】を書いているときに感じたことですが、ストレートに質問するより、まず自分としての回答（my attempt）を提示した後で質問する方が、回答者は質問の趣旨も良く分かりますし、回答もしやすいように思います。